# Inspect current exception in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

If a Java application throws an unhandled exception, it causes Eclipse to break at that point. Is there a way to inspect the current exception? Basically, `$exception` from MSVS?

Comment: Eclipse is breaking? How about just looking at the eclipse log file to see what caused this?

Comment: @smox Well if you have used MSVS's `$exception` you would know what I mean. That allows you to type in the Expressions view to watch the current exception and view various fields of it interactively.

Comment: Okay, I read the original question completely wrong :) ... Can't you just press higher in the StackTrace and then see the variables on the exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breakpoint at exception in Eclipse - how to examine Exception object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453746/breakpoint-at-exception-in-eclipse-how-to-examine-exception-object)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In think the problem described occurs when making use of **Exception breakpoint**, in which case you don't have access to the exception variable and can't inspect it in the variables view.

I found a "solution" to this problem in the following post: [Breakpoint at exception in Eclipse - how to examine Exception object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453746/breakpoint-at-exception-in-eclipse-how-to-examine-exception-object)

It is:

> There is an option in the Eclipse Preferences that allows inspecting
>   of the thrown exception:
>
> Check Java -> Debug -> Open popup when suspended on exception
>
> With this option there will be a popup allowing inspection of the
>   exception.
>
> Strange that this option is not checked by default as it is very
>   useful !

Comment: This is great, but a follow-up question I have is how do you get it back if you switch applications? I switched to SO to up-vote the answer and when I went back to eclipse the popup had closed. MSVS FTW.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I set this option. Add an exception breakpoint for NullPointException. Ran my application in the debugger.  Caused a NullPointerException to be thrown. The debugger just stops the application as expected. But no window or dialog opens up with the exception details. In fact the behavior is exactly as before.

Comment: Frankly, I've been trying to answer this question for over 5 years now. I'm regularly shocked that you can stop on an exception but are refused any further details about the exception that stopped you.

Comment: @dcstraw I've just searched about the same thing, it's been causing my headaches. The solution with the popup is actually really great! I've noticed that you *can* bring the popup with the exception details back, even after switching applications. To do that, simply click on the *line of the process with an exception* in the "Debug" view (it's the one saying `Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException))`)

Comment: This used to work but doesn't seem to work in Kepler no more :/

Comment: @kizzx2 it has been fixed (reportedly): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404784#c3

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inspect the Exception object, set up a breakpoint inside the catch block, or set up an Exception breakpoint, and hover over the variable while at the breakpoint.

```
try {
    ...code...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Hover over the e, or open the Eclipse Variables view and add the name of the exception variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing out the obvious :/ but looks like the answer is "no you can't" then :(

Comment: How is this a “no?” From either the hover or the Variables view, you can drill down into any field of the Exception … what's different from `$exception`?

Comment: @BRPocock `$exception` does not require a recompile or stopping the application in the middle of a heated debugging session

Comment: Nor does this require a recompile… aside from the fact that the exception will have stopped that thread, of course?

Comment: @BRPocock Well I think I was not clear about it on the outset. Let's say I only have the `...code...` section above (without the try-catch block). `...code...` throws, and I want to inspect the exception right there. I would need to stop the execution, go to the editor and add the try-catch block. This is not the case with `$exception`

Comment: @BRPocock The crux of my issue is that without the try catch block _already in place_, the exception is unnamed, and thus cannot be inspected by Eclipse. To be able to name it, I need to go back to the code and add the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go to the 'Variables' view and look for the variable that holds the exception (usually e), but I think it depends on the specific context in which the exception occurs, this is not an Eclipse information like you are asking for.

Answer (score -1):

In the debug perspective of eclipse find the "Breakpoints" view. Now find the tool bar icon with a little "J" and a "!", the tooltip for it should read "Add Java Exception Breakpoint". When you click this toolbar icon a window opens where you can type in an exception name and find the one you want. Make sure that "Suspend on Uncaught Exceptions" is checked. You may also want to uncheck "Suspend on Caught Exceptions" or you will probably suspend/break way to often on exceptions that are already handled appropriately in your code. Then click "OK".

You will now see your exception type in in the list of breakpoints and you can run your Java application in debug mode. Eclipse will suspend/break on the uncaught exception and you can then debug and look at variables and such. (Remember you can click on the call stack and look at other variables and methods)

In the breakpoints list you can uncheck your exception type to no longer suspend/break on that particular exception. This is convenient so you don't have to remove/add in typical exception types all the time. You can imagine that I have NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, among others all added to my list and toggle them on/off as needed.

Comment: The question is how to inspect the exception (it is already breaking on an exception).