# eclipse console doesn't show the exception

Tags: java

"The default handler displays a string describing the exception, prints a
stack trace from the point at which the exception occurred, and terminates the program."
But this doesn't happen. Every time i intentionally create a DivideByZero exception but provide no exception handler, the default handler should have displayed a string with stack trace but my console is empty and program is not terminated only exception it shows is in debug panel. It may be small problem but every where i look the exception should have been printed in console but myconsole is empty.

I use eclipse neon.

---

*Update [from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433778/eclipse-console-doesnt-show-the-exception/43434306#comment73925635_43433778):*

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(10/0);
    }
}
```

This should give `ArithmeticException` but there is nothing displayed at console.

Comment: Show us your code.  A divide by zero is a runtime exception and should throw an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: public class Example {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println(10/0);
 }
}
this should give ArithmeticException but there is nothing displayed at console. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `Run` the program, it will print stacktrace.

If you `Debug` the program, the debugger will (by default) **halt execution** when an *uncaught* exception is thrown, but it will (by default) not show the exception. Select `Resume (F8)` to continue execution, and the program will end and print stacktrace.

If you don't intend to debug the program, choose `Run` to start the program, not `Debug`.

If you want to debug, but don't want to halt execution on uncaught exception, open `Window` > `Preferences`, go to `Java` > `Debug`, and uncheck `Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions`.

If you still want to halt execution on uncaught exception, but you also want to actually *see* the exception, open `Window` > `Preferences`, go to `Java` > `Debug`, and check `Open popup when suspended on exception`. *Source: [Inspect current exception in Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8853602/5221149)*

<sup>*Note: The above is from Eclipse Mars.2, not Neon, but should be the same.*</sup>

Comment: This really helped. Thanks a million. @Andreas