# spring boot war packaging fails because of wrong database access credentials

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, war

I am trying to deploy my spring boot app to a private JVM, the application is running successful on my local setup and I can build war easily, in my application.properties file I have my database connection properties for my local database, after I changed them to the credentials of the database in the host, the maven build is failing with exception:

```
  Host 'X.X.X.X' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I do not understand why in there is attempt to access the mysql server during the build?

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myproject</name>
<description>description of my project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <start-class>com.levels.website.LevelsApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.mobile/spring-mobile-device -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which maven command do you use to build?

Comment: mvn clean install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL internally have table which defined host which are allowed to connect to server. You need to add IP of your server in those table. [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: I am just building my war file, why do i need to connect to server during the build?

Comment: any testcase using datasource?

Comment: I do not have any test cases

Comment: I will suggest just remote connect maven build and put some exception breakpoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453746/breakpoint-at-exception-in-eclipse-how-to-examine-exception-object..

Comment: I found out that there was default unit test in my app causing this issue, I solved it by skipping the test.